# Get answer from Google Dictionary API using ruby win Portuguese and accented characters

Tags: ruby, dictionary, diacritics

I'm trying to get results from the Google Dictionary API with ruby. It works well with non accented characters but does not work with accented characters (i.e. if you type directly the URL into the address bar of the browser).
If you use the chrome browser you get good answers either with accents or no accents.
I already jumped over the problem of the URI parser not linking URLs with accents using the following code

```
require "addressable"
require "net/http"

begin
    uri = Addressable::URI.convert_path('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/pt-BR/há')
    p uri
rescue => error
    p error
end

response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
p response
```

I get an empty response, while using the browser I get the correct response.

Can somebody suggest some workaround? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but it continues to no work as expected. If you provide the uri encoded then the Google API does not recognize the word.

Comment: Just to finish if you use

Comment: https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/pt-BR/&#xe1;guas

Comment: You get a wrong answer from the google API. If you use the accented character (on the browser) then you get the correct answer. I will have the dwelve futher on this ... Thx anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig deep inside `addressable` gem.

But here is a working example with [`URI`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/URI.html) and [`JSON`](https://github.com/flori/json):

```rb
require "net/http"
require "json"
begin
    uri = URI.parse(URI.encode('https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/pt-BR/há'))
    p uri
rescue => error
    p error
end

 response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
 p JSON.parse(response)
 => 
 [
  {
   "word"=>"ha",
   "phonetics"=>[{}],
   "meanings"=>[
     {
       "partOfSpeech"=>"undefined",
       "definitions"=>[{"definition"=>"símb. de HECTARE.", "synonyms"=>[], "antonyms"=>[]}]}
    ]
  },
  {
    "word"=>"hã",
    "phonetics"=>[{}],
    "origin"=>"⊙ ETIM voc.onom.",
    "meanings"=>[
      {
        "partOfSpeech"=>"interjeição",
        "definitions"=>[
          {
            "definition"=>"expressa reflexão, esclarecimento, admiração.", "synonyms"=>[], "antonyms"=>[]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx for all your answers so far but it seems that the problem is on the API (that is no longer maintained by Google).
What is happening in your last example with that the word 'hà' is transformed in 'ha' i.e the accent is removed and the semantics are lost.

I will try another way.